# Sonar executing multiple times in a Multi-Configuration Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

We are having some problems with configuring a multi-configuration build
with Sonar.

I want to compile and test a project with multiple jdks' (6 and 7) to
make sure the project is functional under both. Additionally I want to
have Sonar execute, however want Sonar to execute on only one of the
builds to avoid executing it multiple times, which would duplicate data
in the Sonar db and waste time.

I have set this up as a multi-configuration project, with the two jvms
as an axis, and Sonar as a post build action. This builds and tests
fine, however it seems to execute Sonar on both builds.

One problem is what is the definition of a "post build action" on a
multi-configuration project. Is it something that executes after each
configuration, or something that is run once after all configurations
have finished. We have a Git publish action that seems to do what I
expect which is run once after all other configurations have been built,
however sonar appears to be the opposite. Is this a quirk of the Sonar
plugin and what it is doing is not really a "post build action"?

Is there any way of configuring a build that would achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the Conditional Build Step Plugin ? 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin
You can define rules and conditions for a build step. 
Keep in mind also that Sonar Can be configured not only as a post build action but as build step as well http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Activate+Sonar+on+Jenkins+job

Comment: Conditional plugin sorted it, we no longer have the sonar as a post build step, which means we miss out on the Sonar icon/link, but that's a small price to pay to not execute Sonar a gazillion times :-)